# Table for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Well i have made a table using grid and labels.
Now i must fix the columns width's.

[image]

I try this:

```
def fix_player_width(self):
    max_widths = []
    for j in range(0,self.total_columns):
        max_widths.append([])
        max_widths[j] = 0

    for j in range(0,self.total_columns):
        for i in range(0,self.total_songs+1):
            #print(self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(i, j))
            width = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[2]-self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(i, j)[0]
            if(max_widths[j]<width):
                max_widths[j] = width

    #print(max_widths)
    for j in range(0,self.total_columns):
        for i in range(0,self.total_songs+1):
            x0 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[0]
            y0 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[1]
            x1 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[2]
            y1 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[3]
            width = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[2]-self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(i, j)[0]
            if(max_widths[j]>width):
                '''text = str(self.player_data[i][j].cget("text"))
                width_fixed = False
                while(not width_fixed):
                    text = text+" "
                    self.player_data[i][j].config(text=text)
                    x0 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[0]
                    y0 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[1]
                    x1 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[2]
                    y1 = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[3]
                    width = self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(j, i)[2]-self.player_songs_main_frame.bbox(i, j)[0]
                    if(max_widths[j]<=width):
                        #what?
                        pass
    '''
```

Now what i must change?
I tried to change width and to put empty spaces.

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

**Edit:** One solution is to put one Label for every character.
But i don't really believe that's a clear solution.

Comment: How are you adding widgets to the screen? Are you using `place`? Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: How I understand it, you are searching for .grid(sticky='nswe'). But not sure if we really talking about tkinter here.

Comment: Where is the code that creates the `Label` widgets? The code you have posted needs some commenta added describing what it's doing.

Comment: I will post details tomorrow.